# Formatear un numero en datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Buenas tardes estimados amigos,

un gusto saludarlos y espero que estén de maravilla, quiero que por favor me ayuden con el siguiente problema, Tengo un datatable y lo cargo con la informacion de la base de datos, de allí todo muy bien. al campo de peso debo convertirlo en gramos y kilos y esto lo hace igualmente bien, lo que no me funciona es cuando lo voy a formatear para dejarlo con 3 decimales, lo he hechos de varias formas e igualmente apoyado con la documentación pero no encuentro la solución, si alguien sabe le agradecería mucho.

```
let tablePesaje = $('#tablePesaje').dataTable({

    ajax: {
        url: `../../api/materiasp/${referencia}`,
        dataSrc: ''
    },
    paging: false,
    info: false,
    searching: false,
    sorting: false,
    
    columns: [
        {
            title: 'Referencia',
            data: 'referencia', className: 'uniqueClassName'
        },
        {
            title: 'Materia Prima',
            data: 'alias', className: 'uniqueClassName'
        },
        {
            title: 'Peso (<a href="javascript:cambioConversion();" class="conversion_weight">g</a>)',
            className: 'conversion_weight_column',
            data: 'porcentaje', className: 'uniqueClassName', //render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 3),
            
            render: (data, type, row) => {
                
                if (flagWeight) {
                    var peso =  parseFloat(data * batch.tamano_lote) ;
                    return peso;
                } else { 
                    peso = (data * batch.tamano_lote)/ 1000;
                    $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 3);
                    return peso;
                }
                //$.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 3);
            },
            
        },
        {
            title: 'No TQ',
            data: 'porcentaje', className: 'uniqueClassName',
            render: (data, type, row) => {
                $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 3);
                if (flagWeight) {
                    return parseInt(data * batch.tamano_lote * 10);
                } else {
                    return ((data * batch.tamano_lote) / 1000) / 10;
                }
            
            },
            
        },
        {
            title: 'Impresión',
            defaultContent: '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imprimirEtiquetas"><i class="large material-icons">print</i></a>', className: 'uniqueClassName'
        }
        
    ],
```

Comment: Intenta remplazando esas 3 líneas con `return = ((data * batch.tamano_lote)/ 1000).toFixed(3);`

Comment: Super, Muchas gracias, era lo que buscaba, amigo un favor como puedo cambiar el punto decimal por coma?

Comment: Después de el último paréntesis agrega `.replace('.', ',')`